# What does "Nothing like anything" mean according to Buddism?

Tags: self, knowledge

I heard "`Nothing like anything`" from many people. I think a lot over it and finally i got it like "`Tyag se he mukti milte h`" and i feel it with my self yes tyag se he mulki milte h but i could not get it remain with my self. Will you please give me a direction so that I could pertain it as remain and what is the the proper meaning of "nothing like anything" according to Buddism because I do not have much knowledge about Buddha teachings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So your question is "`Tyag se he mukti milte h`" which means sacrifice, renowned and non attachment will bring Salvation.

Nothing like anything is never said by Buddha.

However coming back to question first of all Lord Buddha's view on salvation is a bit tricky if you are coming from a Hindu background, by that I mean you are not supposed to sacrifice anything just remain in the middle, as Lord Krishna also said **remain in tranquility** or there should be equanimity in life.

As the question has been asked on Buddhism, So lets stick with buddha's view.

So the aim to be always **remain conscious**, which seems to be impossible but with practice you will start realizing that you are doing better.

Sit silently and start by focusing on breath, just **observe your breath for 3 minutes** in starting and **do this at least three to six times a day**, which should be easy you are android developer.

Now also try to use **30 second rule** multiple times a day, which in short is to try to remain in the present moment.

Now lets say you feel good in meditation and at some point bad, Buddhism approach is that you will not get flown by mind in either of the above said situation, **do not get excited when feeling good** and **do not feel depressed on feeling bad**, just OBSERVE.

OBSERVATION is very powerful

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like anything means incomparable; completely different from all other things. This is applied to Supreme Buddha Himself. It is because there can be only one Samma Sambuddha, in the entire universe, at any given period. During most aeons (Kalpa), there are no Samma Sambuddhas. Hence they are very rare. A Samma Sambuddha is called ‘Asama Sama’, i.e. incomparable with any other being but can be compared only to other Samma Sambuddhas who had lived in the distant past. Hence it is not feasible for all to aspire to be a Buddha.

This is also a truism for the Dhamma. "Dhamma" nothing but The Teachings of the Supreme Buddha. The Dhamma is the second of the Three Jewels of Buddhism of which practitioners of Buddhism seek refuge in (what one relies on for his/her lasting happiness). The truth and meaning of Dhamma becomes a private experience by the wise only when there is INSIGHT or vipassana. But insight (vipassana) depends on samadhi or CONCENTRATION. And concentration (samadhi) depends on Sammaditthi or RIGHT VIEW.

The Arya Sangha – the Arahants – too are like no other. We know that “Arahant disciples” of the Buddha have no re-births. Because the cause for rebirth was overcome and the Patticca Samuppada (Law of Cause and Effect) was defeated, there is no birth due to Bhava or the formation of Kamma to result in a birth (“Bhava paccaya jāti” as noted in Patichcha Samuppada) for Arahants. This is why Arahants are completely free from being born again, and are the third of the ‘Nothing like Anything’ .